# Pandas read_table never fails

Tags: python, pandas, flask, pytest, flask-sqlalchemy

Trying to learn a bit of python and test that the incoming binary data ( which is a file ) is tab-delimited. Whatever kind of string I turn into binary does not break the pandas `read_table` parser. I am not sure what is going here and am at the end of the rope.

Seems pretty standard that I should be able to test the data before turning it into a pandas `DataFrame`.

```
@app.route("/api", methods=['POST'])
def handle_upload():
    data = request.get_data()
    print(type(data))
    if data:
        try:
            df = pd.read_table(BytesIO(data), delim_whitespace=True)
        except IOError as e:
            return Response('incorrect format, no tab delimitation', status=422)
        
        try:
            if not all(item in df.columns for item in COLUMNS):
                raise ValueError
        except pd.errors.InvalidColumnName:
            return Response('Incorrect column values', status=422)
        
        sorted_by_score = df.sort_values(by='score', ascending=False)
        ten_of_largest_score = sorted_by_score[0:10]
        
        sqlite_connection = engine.connect()            
        ten_of_largest_score.to_sql(sqlite_table, sqlite_connection, if_exists='replace')
        sqlite_connection.close()

        return Response('file uploaded successfully', status=201)


    def test_handle_upload_invalid_format(client):
        response = client.post('/api', data=b'"invalid_data_without_tab_delimiter"')
        assert response.status_code == 422
```

Comment: What does the data look like and why should `read_table` fail? If there's no tab, the entire line is a single cell

Comment: So essentially there is no test I can make to prove that there are values in the file and they are tab delimited?

Comment: I suspect what you really want is to validate the contents of the dataframe. At the very least, verify that `df.columns` contains the columns you want. You can use libraries like pandera or pydantic (pydantic for Pandas) to verify types and contents as well

Comment: I do have a test for columns already. Maybe I skip this then. Thanks my Greek brethren.

Comment: I use Pandera schemas to validate files sent by external partners, using types, regular expression patterns and even multi-column checks. The files are generated manually, so not only does each partner use their own schema, they may change it from one month to the other. Using a [pandera schema](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/dataframe_schemas.html) lets me easily check that the dataframes contain the expected data or tell me what check failed.